# Create file in project's directory

Tags: jsp

I'm using this to create a text file (which is expected to be in project's directory) with some content, but when running project, nothing happens.

```
<%
String strPath = "example.txt";
File strFile = new File(strPath);
boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();

Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
objWriter.write("This is a test");
objWriter.flush();
objWriter.close();
%>
```

It works if I replace **"example.txt"** with **"C:\example.txt"**, or running this in a Java application.
Do I really have to give full directory to `strPath`, to just create the file at my project directory? If I do, how to get project's directory?

Comment: There are no projects at runtime. Your question is ill-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by all i know it should work, try this to find out where the file is created:

```
File nopath = new File("text.xml");
System.out.println(nopath.getCanonicalPath());
```

and then check if it created there.

from here you can play with it as you like. for example if i want the file to be written in the given path parent folder i'll do:

```
File nopath = new File("../text.xml");
```

and i wanted the file to be created in a sub folder of the parent i'll do

```
File nopath = new File("../myFolder/text.xml");
```

Comment: OMG, thank you very much. I got the path and the file was created there, is there a way that I can change this path?

Comment: yes, the regular "../" or use absolute path, i'll reedit the answer

Comment: Well, this is a homework and my project will be run on my teacher's computer, so I can't just give it a static directory. Is there a way that I can get my project's directory?

Comment: i think not. you see, when you open a program, you get the environment path, or program path. if that's you project path, yay! if not, you'll have to know where is your project path in relation to the environment path. of course, you can scan the entire hard drive

Comment: I see. Anyways, your answer helped a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: glad to be of service